# Absolute Path File Not Found

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

[File Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kd6f2.png)I'd like to understand why can't VS code follow the absolute path in this script tag. Here is the file directory and the code that I am using. I am using JavaScript's history API in order to create a single page application. Is there a better method than using the history API?

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Grand Buffet</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/grandbuffet.css">

</head>
<body>
<header>
    <nav>
        <img class="grandbuffet" src="static/css/assets/GrandBuffet2.png" alt="GrandBuffet">
        <ul class="tabs">
            <li class="tab is-active">
                <a href="/" data-link>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab">
                <a href="/aboutus" data-link>About Us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab">
                <a href="/menu" data-link>Menu</a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab">
                <a href="/locations" data-link>Locations</a>
            </li>
            <li class="order-now">
                <a href="/ordernow" data-link>Order Now</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>

<div class="main-section">
        Hi
</div>
<div id="app"></div>
<footer>
    <div class="footer-content">
        <p>2022 Grand Buffet All rights reserved</p>
        <div class="social-media">
            <img src="static/css/assets/insta_blk.png" class="instagram" alt="Instagram">
            <img src="static/css/assets/twit_blk.png" class="twitter" alt="Twitter">
            <img src="static/css/assets/youtube_blk.png" class="youtube" alt="YouTube">
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>      
<script type="module" src="/static/js/index.js"> </script>
</body>
</html>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the first "**/**", VS code may be trying to find the file starting from the root directory of the project, not from where index.html is located. Or, use "**./**" (Notice the period at the start, is important) that way your specefying the actual directory where index.html is.